# Checking populated array in Swift4

Tags: arrays, swift

Keep getting error Value of type `[String]` has no member `removeAtIndex`
Does any help, please?
Thanks

```
var strings2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

if strings2.isEmpty {
print("empty")

}
else {
 print("populated")                   // populated
}
strings2.insert("a", at: 0)            // Insert, not replace
print(strings2.removeAtIndex(0))          // a
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is called [remove(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641390-remove).

```
print(strings2.remove(at: 0))
```